# Exchange Web Services Office 365 throws 404 error

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

All of a sudden the code that used to work last week for sending email through Office 365 EWS no longer works, and I'm trying to figure out why (if here has been a change on our network leading to this behavior or something on the Office 365 end)

Code is pretty simple:

```
                    ExchangeService myservice = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
                myservice.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username@domain.com", "password");
                myservice.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx");
                EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage(myservice);
                emailMessage.Subject = "Subject";
                emailMessage.Body = new MessageBody("Body");
                emailMessage.From = "username@domain.com";
                emailMessage.ReplyTo.Add("username@domain.com");
                emailMessage.ToRecipients.AddRange("anotheruser@domain.com");
                emailMessage.Send();
```

The line `emailMessage.Send()` throws an error: "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Stack Trace:

```
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1 items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.InternalSend(FolderId parentFolderId, MessageDisposition messageDisposition)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.Send()
   at Metro.MicrosoftExchange.SendEmail(String senderEmailAddress, String[] recipientEmailAddresses, String emailSubject, String emailBody, Dictionary`2 emailAttachments) in C:\Users\nick.goloborodko.METSTH\Documents\MetroEmail\MetroEmail\MicrosoftExchange.cs:line 152
```

I'm really stuck right now and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first thing I would suggest you test is the username and password are okay. Eg logon to the office365 Portal an expired password can produce weird error like this (or maybe somebody has removed the licence from the account etc)

Comment: You've beat me to it :) The username had a typo in it - it's just that the error message has been extremely misleading.